# Unwrapping problem, UV only takes up a small space

Tags: uv

After having marked the seams of my mesh (a building) when I want to unwrap, all the UVs are concentrated on the left and in height, the same thing happens with the smart UV project option. If anyone can help me, I thank him in advance

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The UV islands try to preserve the aspect ratio. Some of the islands are too long.